# Передача значений по ссылке

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели

Объявите указатель на массив типа int и выделите память для N элементов.
необходимо написать функцию, которая поменяет значения четных и нечетных ячеек массива.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void changer();
    int *parr;
    int N;
    cin>> N;
    parr = new int [N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        parr[i] = i;
    changer(&parr, N); //ВОТ ТУТ ВОТ ПРОБЛЕМА У МЕНЯ

    return 0;
}
void changer (int *parr, int N)
{
    int tmp;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        if (i %2 != 0)
        {
            tmp = parr[i];
            parr[i] = parr[i-1];
            parr[i-1] = tmp;
        }

}
```

Как правильно передать параметр в функцию?

Comment: Какая именно проблема там у вас?

Comment: прочтите  внимательнее

Comment: Прочел внимательно. Не указаны сообщения об ошибках этапа компиляции, этапа выполнения. Не указано реальное поведение кода, только ожидаемое. Что же еще мне почитать?

Comment: changer(&parr, N); поменяйте на changer(parr, N);

Comment: я даже не компилировал этот код, т.к. у меня синтаксическая ошибка    changer(&parr, N) где я пытаюсь передать по ссылке параметр. Вот и хочу узнать как правильно. Почему "-" ?

Comment: Я и исправил Вашу ошибку. переменная parr у Вас типа int*, я не понимаю, зачем Вы передаете ее адрес в функцию.

Comment: неверно. пишет "слишком много аргументов"

Comment: И поэтому вы предлагаете другим попробовать это собрать или угадать какая же именно у вас ошибка?

Comment: Ну и для чистоты эксперимента переместите Вашу функцию changer выше main

Comment: Я всего лишь спросил как мне правильно передать параметр в функцию, и в коде указал проблемное место

Comment: мне нужно передать функции ссылку на динамический массив. Потому и int *parr

Comment: changer(parr, N) вот так.  & убрать нужно было

Comment: http://prntscr.com/77ibv5

Comment: А ну да, не заметил ошибку. В функции main у вас написано void changer(); убирайте это оттуда. Я понял, что вы хотели написать прототип функции: для этого ПЕРЕД функцией main напишите строчку void changer(int*, int);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Слишком много аргументов" у вас пишется из-за неправильного использования прототипа функции `changer()`. Который зачем-то объявлен внутри `main()` (ну это ладно). Но главное - объявлена функция без аргументов, а вызываете вы её с двумя. Либо уберите прототип вообще и поместите тело функции `changer` перед `main()` (хорошим тоном было бы и объявить её как `static`, если не планируется использовать её вне этого модуля). Либо объявите правильный прототип:

```
void changer (int *, int);
```

P.S. Постановка вопроса, конечно :) В сообщении об ошибке написано одно, а спрашиваете совсем про другое...

Comment: так и спрашиваю ведь КАК мне передать параметр

Comment: понял ошибку, моя невнимательность. +

Comment: А почему не стоит объявлять прототип внутри main?

Comment: Ошибки, связанные с неверными параметрами, выглядят совсем не так. Например (если вместо `int*` передавать `float`): `cannot convert 'float' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void changer(int*, int)'` Здесь же явно говорится о **количестве** аргументов.